# Checking for only column value to be present in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following below dataframe :

```
          col1                col2         col3
0          1601286            NAN         NAN
1          1601286            1135         2018-12-31
2          1601286            NAN         NAN
3          1601286            1135         2018-12-31
4          1601286            NAN         2018-12-31
5          1601286            1135         2018-12-31
6          1601286            1135         2018-12-31
7          1601286            1135         2018-12-31
8          1601286            NAN        NAN
```

I need to put a validation that only one out of these 3 columns should have a value . If more than one is notnull(), it should be a `False`.

For example, the output of above data should be ,

```
0 True
1 False
2 True
3 False
4 False
5 False
6 False
7 False
8 True
```

trying to do something like below which is for sure will not work:-

```
df= df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].notnull().any(axis=1)
```

How can I handle this.

Comment: Should the validation be `True` or `False` when there are more than one `NaN` per row?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.isnull.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df.isnull().sum(1).eq(2)
```

or:

```
df.isnull().sum(1).gt(1)
```

or:

```
df.notnull().sum(1).lt(2)
```

or:

```
df.notnull().sum(1).eq(1)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Perfect solution :)

Comment: @Sandeep I thought I would be able to solve my issue with this . Can you help me in this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946579/checking-for-only-one-group-of-columns-values-to-be-present-in-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1601286,np.NaN,np.NaN],
[1601286,1135,2018-12-31],
[1601286,np.NaN,np.NaN],
[1601286,1135,2018-12-31],
[1601286,np.NaN,2018-12-31],
[1601286,1135,2018-12-31],
[1601286,1135,2018-12-31],
[1601286,1135,2018-12-31],
[1601286,np.NaN,np.NaN]], columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

df['count_notnull']=df.count(axis=1)                # Will give a count of non-NULLs.
df['bool'] = df['count_notnull'].map(lambda x:x==1) # Since we need only 1 non-Null, 
                                                    # so we test the condition here.

df

      col1    col2    col3  count_notnull   bool
0  1601286     NaN     NaN              1   True
1  1601286  1135.0  1975.0              3  False
2  1601286     NaN     NaN              1   True
3  1601286  1135.0  1975.0              3  False
4  1601286     NaN  1975.0              2  False
5  1601286  1135.0  1975.0              3  False
6  1601286  1135.0  1975.0              3  False
7  1601286  1135.0  1975.0              3  False
8  1601286     NaN     NaN              1   True
```

Comment: Can you help me in this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946579/checking-for-only-one-group-of-columns-values-to-be-present-in-dataframe

Comment: I can try. Give me some moments.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.isnull` together with `pandas.sum` and then check your condition. For example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'A':[1, 2, 3, np.NaN, 5], 'B':[1, 2, np.NaN, np.NaN, 5], 'C':[1, 2, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]}
print(pd.DataFrame(d).isnull().sum(axis=1)>1)
```

Output

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you help me in this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946579/checking-for-only-one-group-of-columns-values-to-be-present-in-dataframe